# How to remove missing value in SAS by a sequence of variables

Tags: sas

Here is the demonstrate data.

```
data faminc;
  input famid faminc1-faminc12;
cards;
1 3281 3413 3114 2500 2700 . 3114 3319 3514 1282 2434 2818
2 4042 . . . . . 1531 2914 3819 4124 4274 4471
3 6015 . . . . . . . . . . .
;
run;
```

I would like to create an indicator variable called fam_indicator. If variables faminc2-faminc12 are all missing, then fam_indicator=1. Otherwise fam_indicator=0.

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
data fam;
set faminc;
if missing(faminc2-faminc12) then fam_indicator=1;
else fam_indicator=0;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a bunch of different ways.  If the variables are all numeric, then `n` will do it for you.

```
data fam;
set faminc;
if n(of faminc2-faminc12) eq 0 then fam_indicator=1;
else fam_indicator=0;
run;
```

`cmiss` and `nmiss` also could work; `cmiss` is generic regardless of type, while `nmiss` is only for numerics.  They would count the number of missings, so you'd want `if cmiss(of faminc2-faminc12) eq 11` or similar.

The other thing you needed was the `of`.  `n(faminc2-faminc12)` would just subtract the one from the other.  `of` says "the next thing here is a variable list" and it will then expand the list out.

Answer (score 0):

nmiss function could be used directly, sum function is also another option, sum of all missing values is still missing value.

```
fam_indicator=ifn(sum(of faminc2-faminc12)=.,1,0);
```